# Any concern about using GAE + Spring + Velocity

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, velocity

I'm just starting a project and decided to use Spring with Appengine.

I'm now looking for a good template engine which integrates easily with Spring and also works on AppEngine.

From what I have seen so far, I'm really enjoining velocity way of doing things..

Do you guys have any pro/cons about using this combination?

Any bad experience?

Thanks a lot for all opinions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to go with what you know.

Spring MVC works well with Apache Velocity.  It also supports JSP and Freemarker.  Each has its enthusiasts.

We've built a sophisticated software-as-a-service web site using the Spring Framework, with Spring MVC and Velocity.  (As a disclaimer, I've been working with Velocity for years and am one of the contributors).  The general feeling in our group is that Spring/Velocity is easy to work with, both for web page and email generation.

I've not tried it with GAE, but see nothing in the GAE restrictions that should prevent it from working properly.

Comment: thank you for your your comments. I'm alredy giving it a shot seems to be working very nice. But GAE is somehow slow :(

Comment: go all the way with velocity! jsp sucks!

Answer (score 2):

I am currently using Spring + Velocity in a production appengine service. It's awesome!

The only component that I didn't incorporated well, at the moment, is the the [DCEVM](http://ssw.jku.at/dcevm/) for not needing to restart the development server when doing changes in the Java classes.

You can also check my post about this: [Spring-mvc + Velocity + DCEVM](http://blog.rafaelsanches.com/2012/02/02/spring-mvc-velocity-dcevm/)